# Counting Hashtag

Tags: python

I'm writing a function called HASHcount(**name**,**list**), which receives 2 parameters, the **name** one is the name of the file that will be analized, a text file structured like this:

```
Date|||Time|||Username|||Follower|||Text
```

So, basically my input is a tweets list, with several rows structured like above. The **list** parameter is a list of hashtags I want to count in that text file. I want my function to check how many times each word of the list given occurred in the tweets list, and give as output a dictionary with each word count, even if the word is missing.

For instance, with the instruction HASHcount(**December**,**[Peace, Love]**) the program should give as output a dictionary made by checking how many times the word Peace and the word Love have been used as hashtag in the Text field of each tweet in the file called December.

Also, in the dictionary the words have to be without the hashtag simbol.

I'm stuck on making this function, I'm at this point but I'm having some issues concerning the dictionary:

```
def HASHcount(name,list):
 f = open(name,"r")
 dic={}
 l = f.readline()
 for word in list:
   dic[word]=0
   for line in f:
     li_lis=line.split("|||")
     li_tuple=tuple(li_lis)
     if word in li_tuple[4]:
       dic[word]=dic[word]+1
return dic
```

Comment: Call me childish, but misspelling `analyzed` made me laugh

Comment: Could you post an example of the input file? Sorry see it now

Comment: This is a good job for a regex. Also, don't use "list" as a variable name in Python, as it's a reserved word.

Comment: You're `having some issues concerning the dictionary`.  What issues exactly?  What isn't doing that you want it to do?  The code could be cleaned up, but other than searching for ("#" + word) in `li_tuple[4]`, I would think it basically works.

Comment: @dylrei Regular expressions are overkill for testing substring membership when you can just use the `in` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code, some of which have already been pointed out, while others (e.g concerning the identification of hashtags in a tweet's text) have not.  Here's a *partial* solution not covering the fine points of the latter issue:

```
def HASHcount(name, words):
    dic = dict.fromkeys(words, 0)
    with open(name,"r") as f:
        for line in f:
            for w in words:
                if '#' + w in line:
                    dic[w] += 1
    return dic
```

This offers several simplifications keyed on the fact that hashtags in a tweet do start with `#` (which you don't want in the `dic`) -- as a result it's not worth analyzing each line since the `#` cannot be present except in the text.

**However**, it still has a fraction of a problem seen in other answers (except the one which just commented out this most delicate of parts!-) -- it can get false positives by partial matches.  When the check is just like `word in linetext` the problem would be huge -- e.g if a word is `cat` it gets counted as hashtag even if present in perfectly ordinary text (on its own or as part of another word, e.g `vindicative`).  With the `'#' +` approach, it's a bit better, but still, prefix matches would lead to a false positive, e.g `#catalog` would erroneously be counted as a hit for `cat`.

As some suggested, regular expressions can help with that.  However, here's an alternative for the body of the `for w in words` loop...

```
    for w in words:
        where = line.find('#' + w)
        if where == -1: continue
        after = line[where + len(w) + 1]
        if after in chars_acceptable_in_hashes: continue
        dic[w] += 1
```

The only issue remaining is to determine which characters can be part of hashtags, i.e, the set `chars_acceptable_in_hashes` -- I haven't memorized Twitter's specs so I don't know it offhand, but surely you can find out.  Note that this works at end of line, too, because `line` has **not** be stripped, so it's known to end with a `\n`. which is not in the acceptable set (so a hashtag at the very end of the line will be "properly terminated" too).

Comment: this seems to work quite well! I also appreciate that clarification about the acceptable chars, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that you are iterating over the lines in the file for each word, rather than the reverse.  Thus the first word will consume all the lines of the file, and each subsequent word will have 0 matches.

Instead, you should do something like this:

```
def hash_count(name, words):
    dic = {word:0 for word in words}
    with open(name) as f:
        for line in f:
            line_text = line.split('|||')[4]
            for word in words:
                # Check if word appears as a hashtag in line_text
                # If so, increment the count for word
    return dic
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using collections module. This worked for me.

```
from collections import defaultdict

    def HASHcount(file_to_open, lst):

        with open(file_to_open) as my_file:
            my_dict= defaultdict(int)


            for line in my_file:

                line = line.split('|||')
                txt = line[4].strip(" ")
                if txt in lst:
                    my_dict[txt] += 1

        return my_dict
```

Comment: This only checks if the entire tweet is equal to any of the words, should be checking if the text *contains* the word in question.

Comment: I thought he was looking just for #people. Not all counts of the word people in the text